# Creating multiple webviews in Xcode

Tags: ios, webview, viewcontroller

I am a new programmer and I'm making my first app, i already made the Android one. I'm having troubles with the webviews in Xcode.

I saw this tutorial [Xcode 5 Creating a Web View](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nup98qHgbq8)

And now I'm able to make one functional webview. My question is: Do I have to create one ViewController by every webview that I'd like to make? Or can i use one ViewController for 50 webviews?

I tried using the same ViewController for two webviews. The first one works, the second one does nothing.

**nsotrosWebViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>



@interface nsotrosWebViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *Nosotros;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *Tienda;



@end
```

**nsotrosWebViewController.m**

```
#import "nsotrosWebViewController.h"



@interface nsotrosWebViewController ()



@end



@implementation nsotrosWebViewController



- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil

{

    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    if (self) {

        // Custom initialization

    }

    return self;

}



- (void)viewDidLoad

{

    [super viewDidLoad];



    // Webview nosotros-spanish

NSURL *nosotrosURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"];

    NSURLRequest *nosotrosRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nosotrosURL];

    [_Nosotros loadRequest:nosotrosRequest ];



    // Webview tienda-spanish

    NSURL *tiendaURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"];

    NSURLRequest *tiendaRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:tiendaURL];

    [_Tienda loadRequest:tiendaRequest ];

}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning

{

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}



@end
```

I also tried creating one ViewController for each webviews but it won't show more than 2 custom ViewControllers on the "Custom class" menu.

Comment: How do you setup your storyboard, can you please explain.

Comment: You can indeed use a single view controller for multiple webviews. Have you connected IBOutlet for your second webView?

Comment: To:  GenieWanted. I did the same for the both webviews... I don't know why the second one doesnt work.

Comment: What does this have to do with the `xcode IDE`? Also `nsotrosWebViewController` needs renaming to `NsotrosWebViewController` Classes start with upper case letters not lower case and the properties `Nosotros` and `Tienda` need renaming to `nosotros` and `tienda` variables should start with lowercase letters. Please read the Apple Coding guidelines documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html

Comment: To: Popeye. Thanks for your answer. I did not know that.

Comment: Please also note I will not get notified if you just put `To: Popeye` the way it works is you need to do @user3774251 so use the `@` symbol.